# Fazer um select count(*) a partir destes executar vários queries consecutivas PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

tenho uma rotina que começa com um SELECT, e a partir deste eu disparo um email para cada registro encontrado.
O problema é que se eu tiver mais de 3 mil registro, meu programa esta estourando a memoria e o programa não executa como deveria...

Encontrei uma solução provisória, que é aumentar o ini_set("memory_limit","256M"), que acredito que não seja a correta...

Pensei em uma forma de fazer um SELECT e a partir deste, fazer outros SELECT'S com uso do LIMIT, dai acredito que seria uma solução perfeita para o meu problema, pois o script não estouraria a memoria....

Só que não tenho ideia de como fazer... 
Como poderei fazer essa magica nesse script????

Comment: Manda 10 e-mails a cada 2 minutos...

Comment: Na empresa que trabalho quando enviava muitos emails de uma vez acontecia isso, solução que criamos foi disparar de 40 em 40 emails. criamos um array auxiliar para disparo. A cada 40 emails era enviado desse array e ele era limpo. tente

Comment: Marconi, eu faço + ou - isso, neste meu SELECT em um campo especifico, ele me traz um conjunto de numeros separados por " ; " e por ele que faço um array e faço um foreach para pegar numero por numero para ser enviado o email....

Dai como posso fazer esse esquema do foreach fazer loop e 40 numeros esperar um certo tempo e depois continuar ???